# How to ignore values when using numpy.sum and numpy.mean in matrices

Tags: python, numpy, sum, mean

Is there a way to avoid using specific values when applying sum and mean in numpy?

I'd like to avoid, for instance, the -999 value when calculating the result.

```
In [14]: c = np.matrix([[4., 2.],[4., 1.]])

In [15]: d = np.matrix([[3., 2.],[4., -999.]])

In [16]: np.sum([c, d], axis=0)
Out[16]:
array([[   7.,    4.],
       [   8., -998.]])

In [17]: np.mean([c, d], axis=0)
Out[17]:
array([[   3.5,    2. ],
       [   4. , -499. ]])
```

Comment: Have you tried using a mask with null values where values = -xxx?

Comment: What values do you want in `[1,1]` corner, inplace of the large negative?  `1`, `masked`, `nan`, something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a masked array:

```
>>> c = np.ma.array([[4., 2.], [4., 1.]])
>>> d = np.ma.masked_values([[3., 2.], [4., -999]], -999)

>>> np.ma.array([c, d]).sum(axis=0)
masked_array(data =
 [[7.0 4.0]
 [8.0 1.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> np.ma.array([c, d]).mean(axis=0)
masked_array(data =
 [[3.5 2.0]
 [4.0 1.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: To get the resulting array you can use `.data` attribute

Comment: Or better, `.filled(0)` or `filled(np.nan)`, in case a whole row is `-999`

Comment: Many of the `np.ma` functions/methods use `filled(something_innocuous)` when calculating new values.  Either that or `compressed` to remove the masked values.

Answer (score 9):

One option is to replace the specific value with `np.nan` and then use [`numpy.nansum`](http://jiffyclub.github.io/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) and [`numpy.nanmean`](http://numpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) as commented by @s.k:

```
import numpy as np
def nan_if(arr, value):
    return np.where(arr == value, np.nan, arr)

np.nansum([nan_if(c, -999), nan_if(d, -999)], axis=0)
#array([[ 7.,  4.],
#       [ 8.,  1.]])

np.nanmean([nan_if(c, -999), nan_if(d, -999)], axis=0)
#array([[ 3.5,  2. ],
#       [ 4. ,  1. ]])
```

Comment: I was interested to find that [`numpy.ma`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#constructing-masked-arrays) seemed to have no usefulness here.  For instance, `np.sum((ma.masked_values(c, -999), ma.masked_values(d, -999)), axis=1)` doesn't give desired output...

Comment: @BradSolomon: use `np.ma.sum`

Comment: @Eric good find, I saw but didn't think it computed element-wise